# Randomize questions in array/answers on buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-xml

I have created a quiz game and I have stored my questions in XML files (One xml file for easy, medium and hard questions) and created an array:

```
        var quiz = XDocument.Load(path);
        _questions = quiz.Descendants("question")
            .Select(q => new Question()
            {
                ID = int.Parse(q.Attribute("id").Value),
                Difficulty = int.Parse(q.Attribute("difficulty").Value),
                QuestionText = q.Element("text").Value,
                Answers = q.Element("answers")
                    .Descendants()
                    .Select(a => a.Value)
                    .ToArray(),
                CorrectAnswer = q.Element("answers")
                    .Descendants()
                    .Select((a, i) => new { node = a.Name, index = i })
                    .First(a => a.node == "correctAnswer").index
            });
    }
```

I was wondering if there was a way of randomizing

1. The questions that are shown and
2. Which answers are on which buttons.

I ask this because, at the minute, the questions are displayed in the exact same order (Goes through the array and literally displays them in order of which they are written) and the correct answer is on the same button every time. I was wondering if there is a way to randomize/shuffle these that won't completely break my program?

EDIT: I now have the randomize questions part sorted, just need to figure out how to randomize the order the answers appear in on the buttons. Example of the XML file:

```
<question id="2" difficulty="1">
<text></text>
<answers>

</answers>
```

Thank you for any help and/or responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ordering by random number when reading data from xml:

```
   var rand = new Random();
   var quiz = XDocument.Load(path);
    _questions = quiz.Descendants("question")
        .Select(q => new Question()
        {
            ID = (int)q.Attribute("id"),
            Difficulty = (int)q.Attribute("difficulty"),
            QuestionText = (string)q.Element("text"),
            Answers = q.Element("answers")
                .Descendants()
                .Select(a => (string)a)
                .OrderBy(a => rand.Next()) // randomizing answers
                .ToArray(),
            CorrectAnswer = (string)q.Element("answers")
                .Descendants("correctAnswer")
                .First() // use value instead of index
        })
        .OrderBy(q => rand.Next()); // randomizing questions
```

Rest of your program will remain as is.

---

I made a refactoring of your project. Results you can get here. You had lot of duplicated duplicated duplicated code code. Try to have single representation of any information in your applications. That will make your projects easy to maintain.

Main points about refactoring:

- Use user controls to group related controls together. I extracted controls related to difficulty selection into `DifficultySelectionControl` and controls related to displaying question and picking answer to `QuestionControl`.
- Use `BringToFront` and `SendToBack` methods to change Z-ordering of controls
- Use events to notify clients of user control about something happened in user control. I created `DifficultySelected` event for notifying that use selected difficulty. And `QuestionAnswered` event for notifying whether current question was answered correctly or not.
- Use custom event arguments to pass additional data to event handlers
- Use enums. `Difficulty.Medium` is much more readable than `2`.
- If you have similar methods in your code, then try to extract common logic into one method. Take a look on handler of question buttons clicks, which I used instead four different handlers in your code.
- Use descriptive names of controls instead of `label1` or `button4`.

There still places for improving. E.g. I see duplication in `DifficultySelectionControl` - all handlers look similar. Also there is duplication of button background colors. You should have single place where color is defined for different states of buttons. Also there is ugly hack for filtering by difficulty (I casted enum to int). And I'd moved answers randomizing into `QuestionControl`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way of doing this with the answers on the buttons? In the XML files, the correct answers have <correctAnswer></correctAnswer> wrapped around them and the wrong answers have <wrongAnswer></wrongAnswer> wrapped around them

Comment: @user2141272 only thing you should change is correct answer verification. Do it via Value instead of index

Comment: So how would I go about that? Changing the <correctAnswer> parts? Sorry for the questions, but I thought it'd be better to ask

Comment: I saw your edit. If I type .First(a => a.Name == "correctAnswer").Value it says cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: @user2141272 sorry, was away. Just change `CorrectAnswer` property of Question to string type. Also use casting to string and int, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Still gives the error and on the line 'CorrectAnswer = (string)q.Element("answers")' the 'string' part is underlined in blue

Comment: @user2141272 have you changed type of `CorrectAnswer` property? Are you using all code above? It should be `CorrectAnswer = (string)q.Element("answers").Descendants("correctAnswer").First()`. When user selects answer, just compare answer text with `question.CorrectAnswer`

Comment: Yes, I used exactly as you said and it's throwing up the same error

Comment: @user2141272 no, you haven't changed your code as I said. It is not showing any errors to me

Comment: I did it exactly as you had written. Here is a .zip of my project - https://www.box.com/s/6u7b9uv9lg608b8gie1h - The randomize question part didn't work properly when I checked (Your initial answer you posted a few hours ago). Sometimes I was clicking the correct answer (as defined in the XML files) and it was saying it was wrong but some of them were fine.

Comment: @user2141272 hold on, I'll check your project

Comment: @user2141272 I checked your sources. And as I stated above, you haven't changed type of CorrectAnswer property. In your code it still has type of `int`, but it should be `string`. Also you need to change correct answer verification. E.g. instead of `button4.Tag.ToString() == "1"` use `button4.Tag.ToString() == button5.Text` (change it in four places and all will work).

Comment: It doesn't work properly; I'm answering the questions with the correct answers but it's not saying that I scored 20 out of 20

Comment: Questions and answers randomized?

Comment: Everything is randomized yes, but it's not recognizing some of the answers as being correct/incorrect. Try and play it and you'll see what I mean (Use the answers from the XML file(s) to get them all correct; I bet you don't score 20 out of 20)

Comment: @user2141272 have you changed code as I stated above? Quote: Also you need to change correct answer verification. E.g. instead of `button4.Tag.ToString() == "1"` use `button4.Tag.ToString() == button5.Text` (change it in four places and all will work).

Comment: Yeah, I definitely changed that in all four places and it's not fully working

Comment: @user2141272 then you should fix it to work with randomized questions. Question was about randomizing questions and answers. Now you should change your program to work with randomized input.

Comment: Ah, that's gonna be a pain to figure out (I'm fairly new to C# so haven't fully grasped it yet). I probably won't be able to figure it out myself but not sure whether to ask on here or not, probably get negative voted into oblivion

Comment: @user2141272 OK, I'll look what's broken in your solution, but later. Right now I'm busy

Comment: Thank you for your help. Email me if you wish - ftmdan@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: Or I suppose you could let me know here if you didn't want to email

Comment: @user2141272 I started refactoring and review, but not finished yet. Suppose I'll have some time at the evening today

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! You don't understand how much I appreciate this! There is a small problem though; It says there are 20 questions in Easy section, 18 in Medium and 19 in Hard when there are 20 questions in each?

Comment: @user2141272 I like doing refactoring :) Just don't have many free time for that :( Glad to here you appreciate my modifications!

Comment: I edited my comment, not quite sure how I could fix the very small problem?

Comment: @user2141272 I modified xml files for testing :) to see if correct file loaded when difficulty changes. There are actually 20, 18 and 19 questions in sample files

Comment: Ahh, silly mistake of me to make! Thank you for this, means that I can learn from it easier. If you don't mind could you remove the link for the program?

Comment: @user2141272 OK, but I'll add some code samples from that later (for answer be useful for others)

Comment: OK. One more quick question; How do I link a toolstrip item to a form? I created the form and tried putting the code in the toolstrip item click handler to open the form but kept getting a load of namespace errors

Comment: @user2141272 sorry, didn't get your question. What do you mean by *linking*?

Comment: For example so that if you go to the menu bar and click 'How to Play' it opens a form that has instructions on how to play.

Comment: @user2141272 in click event handler add `AboutForm form = new AboutForm(); form.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Yeah, I have named everything correctly and have `private void miHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AboutForm form = new AboutForm(); form.ShowDialog(); }` and it says `The type or namespace name 'AboutForm' could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` in the MainForm.cs file

Comment: I have another problem. I have to put my project into Visual Studio 2010 and I had been using 2012 and I made significant progress but now some of my functions don't work at all when the code hasn't changed and forms don't open when clicking buttons. This is a disaster!